# Role of the Executors on the Spark master machine

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-standalone

In a Spark stand alone cluster, does the Master node run tasks as well? I wasn't sure if there Executors processes are spun up on the Master node and do work, alongside the Worker nodes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Executors would only be started on the nodes where there is at least one worker daemon on that node, i.e, No executor would be started up in a node that do not serve as Worker.

However, Where to start Master and Workers are all based on your decision, there isn't such limitations that Master and Worker cannot co-locate on a same node.

To start a worker daemon the same machine with your master, you can either edit the `conf/slaves` file to add the master ip in it and use start-all.sh at start time or  start a worker at any time you want on the master node, `start-slave.sh` and supply the Spark master URL `--master spark://master-host:7077`

Update *(based on Daniel Darabos's suggestion)* :

When referring to `Application Detail UI`'s `Executors` tab, you could also find a row has `<driver>` for its `Executor ID`, the driver it denotes is the process where your job is scheduled and monitored, it's running the `main` program you submitted to the spark cluster, slicing your transformations and actions on RDDs into stages, scheduling the stages as TaskSets and arranging `executors` to run the tasks.

This `<driver>` will be started on the node which you call `spark-submit` in `client mode`, or on one of the worker nodes in `cluster mode`

Comment: The Spark UI on the Executors tab lists one executor for the application driver as well. Could you cover it as well in your answer for completeness? Thanks!

Comment: @DanielDarabos, thanks for your recommendation, it's very useful. I would edit my answer :)

Comment: Thanks! Sounds roughly correct. I thought the `<driver>` executor was not managing stages and RDDs, but was more like the other executors. It's only used when `allowLocal=true` in [`sc.runJob`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.3.1/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala#L1451). But I've never been too sure about how this works — I could very well be wrong.

Comment: @DanielDarabos, I do not agree with you on the `<driver>`'s role I mentioned above. You know, when we write an application, we would use `sparkContext`, the DAGScheduler that you actually called when `sc.runJob` is the real staff that slice job into stages, `TaskScheduler` is also there in SparkContext.

Comment: I think `runJob` is running in the driver application, but not in the `<driver>` executor. It's in the same JVM, so the distinction is academic at best. Your explanation makes sense too.

Comment: @DanielDarabos, I don't quite understand what you mean by `<driver> executor` and `driver`, can you explain more?

Comment: I'm not so sure myself, sorry :).